# Как завершить процесс с помощью Python и узнать ИД процесса

Tags: python

Есть необходимость в цикле запускать сторонний файл (в данном случае Telegram.exe), и после некоторых манипуляция завершить процесс. Вроде из самых простых способов - это kill()... но все это сделать можно если знаешь ИД процесса, но в данном случае он всегда разный, и мы не знаем его на момент закрытия..

Подскажите пожалуйста, как ИД вообще можно перехватить, или как по другому можно завершить нужный процесс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поставить [wmi](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/) (*всего 28 kb*) и получить список всех процессов в Windows, оттуда и брать ID, который необходимо убить с `kill()`.

```console
pip install wmi
```

```python
import wmi
f = wmi.WMI()

for process in f.Win32_Process():
    if process.Name == 'Telegram.exe':
        print(process.ProcessId)
```

---

Чтобы быстрее работало, не идём по всем процессам, а делаем фильтр средствами библиотеки. Отрабатывает за **86ms** вместо **5s**:

```python
for process in f.Win32_Process(name = 'Telegram.exe'):
    print(process.ProcessId)
```

Comment: оу.. спасибо огромное 

Comment: @Deniis у меня, правда, wmi как-то долго работает. Делал примерно то же на ruby, там гораздо быстрее срабатывало. Возможно есть более шустрая библиотека. И, в зависимости от задачи, если процесс запускать с pywinauto, то там его же можно будет и убить не прибегая к wmi.

Comment: да, уже попробовал и правда долговато... но для текущей задачи пока норм. pywinauto тоже не слышал, почитаю. Спасибо!

Comment: @Deniis да поторопился я с ответом. Дополнил более быстрым вариантом.